# How to use custom SharedPreferences name with AndroidX Preferences Library?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, androidx

I'm using `SharedPreferences` with a custom `SharedPreferences`-names in my project, unfortunately the [`AndroidX Preferences Library`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) seems not to be able to deal with it.

Using this library to create my Settings `Activity` / `Fragment` will always get / set `SharedPreferences` in the `Default SharedPreferences` - is there any way to pass my `SharedPreferences` names to actually access / edit the data in those different instances?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use specific SharedPreferences on your settings screen, you can call this right before you call `setPreferencesFromResource()` in `onCreatePreferences()`:

```
preferenceManager.sharedPreferencesName = "mySpecificPreferences"
preferenceManager.sharedPreferencesMode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this approach finally worked!
I tried overriding getPreferenceManager() before, but without success...

Answer (score 0):

The also variant that works for me:

```
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("your_file_name_pref);
```